# Sql restrict insert records for the same client based on 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE Records
(
    Id INT,
    Client INT,
    IsActive BIT,
    HasSession BIT
)
```

I tried using OR statement but it only considered the 2nd argument.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX F 
    ON ClientsDB.Records (Client)  
    WHERE IsActive = 1;  

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX F 
    ON ClientsDB.Records (Client)  
    WHERE HasSession = 1;
```

I tried doing some research and seems you cannot use OR statement on these

As per trigger suggestion referred, one of my requirements is to avoid them at all so i cannot use anything related to triggers.

Comment: If one of those is set to 1, should an insert be allowed where both columns are 0?

Comment: no, both are needed to be set to 0 to be allowed a new record for same client, so if either one of em is true, they can't make a new record

Comment: `CHECK CONSTRAINT`?

Answer (score 3):

It appears to me that this was asked with a similar context in a [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255730/create-trigger-prevent-insert).

Using that as a foundation I think a `Create Trigger` will give you what you are looking for.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UniqueClient ON dbo.Records
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Records r 
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON r.Client = i.Client 
    WHERE r.IsActive = 1 
    OR r.HasSession = 1
)
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('This Client Already Exists with an Active account or Session', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN 
END;
```

The Key to this process is if the incoming row (represented in the `inserted` table) matches an existing client and that existing client has `IsActive = 1 OR HasSession = 1`, SQL will roll back the transaction and stop the insert.  An error message is sent back to the application prior to the rollback.

Does this give you what you are looking for?

Comment: It does look good but one of my requirements is to avoid triggers at all cost, i should have added this. ill update main post

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way i managed to solve this problem

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [XI_hRegistos_IsActivo]
    ON [dbo].[Records]([Client] ASC, [IsActive] ASC) WHERE ([IsActive]=(1));


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [XI_hRegistos_IsArranqueActivo]
    ON [dbo].[Records]([Client] ASC, [HasSession] ASC) WHERE ([HasSession]=(1));
```

Comment: Glad to see this solved your problem.  I think this may have an unforeseen consequence of impacting `UPDATE` statements as well.  For example if one person with `Client = ABC` gets a session (`HasSession` is set to `1`).  A different record with the same `Client` value now can't acquire a session for itself either.  The attempt to set that 2nd record with `Client = ABC` (set `HasSession = 1`) would fail the unique index of `[XI_hRegistos_IsArranqueActivo]`.  I would either test that situation to see if it will cause an issue for you on the App Side or not.

Comment: Thanks but i tested this and it does exactly as intended, as per requirement 'HasSession = 1' or 'IsActive = 1' is allowed only per client, they can make a new record once both those booleans are 0 again. There's only one problem is that if Has Session is set to 1 and IsActive is set to 0, the client can still make a new record,